# how to create ,update ,delete Places to Firebase Database and Show on google map android app

Tags: firebase

how write ,update ,delete Places to Firebase Database and Show on google map android application for this?

source code for this programe .!

Comment: You need to show us what you did till now. We are not producing code here. We may help you a bit with finding error, better solutions etc. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What exactly have you tried that doesn't work the way you expect? Please respond using @AlexMamo